# XML to xQuery, replace empty or missing node with " "

Tags: xml, xquery, informatica

I have xQuery code that parses an XML response and outputs it to a csv file. The XML response that I am parsing sometimes has nodes missing if they are not used. This is causing issues in the csv outputs as there is no "," returned to seperate the cells, resulting in rows with different number of rows.The code below shows what i currently have:

```
concat("HolidayEndDate,HolidayType,FirstName,AllowanceRemainingDays,HolidayStartDate,EmployeeId,AllowanceDays,LastName,HolidayDurationDays&#10;",
string-join(
    for $b in /root/Result
    return 
      concat(escape-html-uri(string-join(($b/HolidayEndDate,
                                      $b/HolidayType,
                                      $b/FirstName,                                                 
                                      $b/AllowanceRemainingDays,
                                      $b/HolidayStartDate,
                                      $b/EmployeeId,
                                      $b/AllowanceDays,
                                      $b/LastName,
                                      $b/HolidayDurationDays
                                      )
                                       /normalize-space(),
                                    ",")
                         ),
             codepoints-to-string(10)), "")
```

Is there a way to check each of the nodes and if they are null or missing simply replace it with " " or ",". Thanks very much, apologies if the explanation isn't clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you form a sequence with e.g.

```
($b/HolidayEndDate,
                                  $b/HolidayType,
                                  $b/FirstName,                                                 
                                  $b/AllowanceRemainingDays,
                                  $b/HolidayStartDate,
                                  $b/EmployeeId,
                                  $b/AllowanceDays,
                                  $b/LastName,
                                  $b/HolidayDurationDays
                                  )
```

any `$b/foo` that doesn't exist will not produce a value. You would need to use e.g. `string($b/foo)` for all those expressions to output an empty string for those `foo` elements that don't exist.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks very much for your help so far. I have implemented your suggestion my wrapping all of my $b/foo with string() when i try to run though i get an error as follows:

XPTY0019 Required item type of first operand of '/' is node(); supplied vale has item type xs:string

Do you have any recommendations with regards to this and could you share a code example to ensure that I am not misunderstanding? Thanks very much

Comment: I guess the error is caused by your attempt to use `/normalize-space()` on the sequence you construct, you will need to change that, use the function on each item either by putting the call into each expression e.g. `normalize-space(string($b/foo))` (you probably only want/need one function call i.e. `normalize-space($b/foo)`) or use a `for return` or in case of XQuery 3 simply use the simple map `!` operator e.g. `(string($b/foo), string($b/bar), string($b/baz))!normalize-space()`. But in any case using solely `normalize-space($b/foo)` on all expressions in that sequence should do.

Comment: Simple example of XQuery 3 is at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Yf/1 with e.g. `root/item!string-join((string(foo), string(bar), string(baz)), ',')` or with https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Yf/2 and `root/item!string-join((normalize-space(foo), normalize-space(bar), normalize-space(baz)), ',')` for the `normalize-space()` use.

Comment: Thanks so much Martin. This is exactly what i needed! everything is showing as expected! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try

`($b/HolidayType/text(),"")[1]`

If you have a null within a sequence, then the null just disappears.

`('A', 'B', 'C', (), 'E')` becomes `('A', 'B', 'C', 'E')`

Comment: Hi Loren, thanks for your suggestion. This isn't exactly what i'm intending to do. Say the normal output is: A,B,C,D,E but in one of the XML objects the C node is missing the at the moment its returning A,B,D,E. What i would like it to return in this example is A,B,,D,E so that the csv knows that there should be a value but its blank. Thanks!